# Ubuntu 12.04 not showing video after upgrade from 11

Tags: ubuntu, video

After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 VLC or any other media player that plays .mov, .mp4, .wmv etc. is playing with a blank screen but audio is fine. It was working on 11 before the upgrade. Any suggestions for a fix? Flash based video (e.g. youtube) works fine.

After some searching I tried installing Ubuntu restricted extras - suspecting a codecs issue, but this has no effect.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off 'Accelerated Video Output - Overlay' in VLC preferences caused all formats of video to render again.

Comment: So I guess something is wrong with accelerated video.. this solution is temporary.

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching for a solution to the same problem and found the answer:

1. go to Tools → Preferences → Video
2. set output to X11 video output and save
3. restart to see the changes

It worked for me.